# Add pixels to existing CSS element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is my trouble.

I'm using a plugin for a lightbox. For some reason, one of the divs is 28px too short. I've looked all over for a solution for this, but nobody seems to be having the same problem.

The solution I've come up with is to find that element (which I have) and create a javascript snippet that will add "28" to the existing number. The height and width is being calculated directly on the div, not in an element in a stylesheet.

Example:

```
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="padding-bottom: 57px; padding-right: 28px; position: absolute; width: 892px; height: 602px; top: 2234px; left: 500px;">
```

I want the Javascript code to add 28 pixels to the width and 55px to the height.

How would I go about doing this?

I would like to say that I'm not looking for just an answer; if you could explain it to me, that would be great. Thanks so much, guys!

Edit: this is how I called the JQuery

Also, this is where you can see the page with the gallery: http://olsencustomhomes.com.previewdns.com/designs/verona-2/#gallery

EDIT FOR KRIS:

Is this the right code? It's in my header

```
<script>



 $(document).ready(function() {
        function changeSize(){
          var colorbox   = $("#colorbox");
          var initWidth  = $("#colorbox").outerWidth();  // get colorbox width
          var initHeight = $("#colorbox").outerHeight(); // get colorbox height


          var newWidth   = 28; // set your desired width
          var newHeight  = 55; // set your desired height
          var height     = initHeight + newHeight; // add heights together
          var width      = initWidth + newWidth;   // add widths together


          colorbox.css({"height" : height, "width": width});

      }

      $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
         changeSize();
      });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Would increasing `padding-bottom` of the div resolve your problem?

Comment: `$(".selector")` should be whatever your selector is. I am not sure where in your code you call colorbox.. but the call back should be added there

Comment: Also you have function `changeSize()` twice.. nested inside of itself.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea where colorbox is called. I'm adding onto a wordpress plugin called "WP Simple Galleries". To clarify: I'm not changing the plugin code. I'm just adding this to my header.

Comment: Do you have access to all of the JS files?

Comment: I updated the code you posted in your question. try using that instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add height and width dynamically. Something like this should work:

```
function changeSize(){
    var colorbox   = $("#colorbox");
    var initWidth  = $("#colorbox").outerWidth();  // get colorbox width
    var initHeight = $("#colorbox").outerHeight(); // get colorbox height


    var newWidth   = 28; // set your desired width
    var newHeight  = 55; // set your desired height
    var height     = initHeight + newHeight; // add heights together
    var width      = initWidth + newWidth;   // add widths together


    colorbox.css({"height" : height, "width": width});

}changeSize();
```

Also if you want to insure your code is happens after the colorbox opens you could use `.ajaxStop()`; Also note, `outerWidht()` and `outerHeight()` will get colorbox width plus the padding and borders.

***To fire function after ajax events are finished:***

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  changeSize();
});
```

**Update:**

Okay, it looks the function fires initially. You can see width is null because the colorbox has not opened. What you want to do is fire the function after the colorbox opens. That is where `ajaxStop()` would come into play. But it might actually be better to use the [colorbox callback function](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/):

[image]

But not after the colorbox opens. So try doing the `ajaxStop()` approach. Also note, if you do this you will need to remove `changeSize();` after function `changeSize()` For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function changeSize(){
      // function stuff
    }

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
      changeSize();
    });
});
```

**Or, Colorbox OnComplete:**

```
$(".selector").colorbox({
    onComplete:function(){
      changeSize();
    }
});
```

**Update 2:**

I am not sure where you are calling colorbox exactly. But I see you have this: [Found here](http://olsencustomhomes.com.previewdns.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-simple-galleries/wp-simple-gallery.js?ver=3.9.1)

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#wpsimplegallery a').colorbox({
        maxWidth: '85%',
        maxHeight: '85%'
    });
});
```

**So try:**

```
   jQuery(function($){
        $('#wpsimplegallery a').colorbox({
            maxWidth: '85%',
            maxHeight: '85%',
            onComplete:function(){
                changeSize();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This solution is straightforward, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Please refer to my edits in the original post to see where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Make sure the `changeSize();` function is inside your `$(document).ready()` function. Also if you hit f12 you can set a breakpoint in dev tools to check if the function is being executed.

Comment: Trying it now, hang on

Comment: Please see my update. Also, thanks soooo much for helping me with this! I'm ready to pully my hair out!

Comment: That would require me to change the plugin code. Is there any way around that?

Comment: The only other way around is probably using `ajaxStop()`. See your updated question. Ideally using the oncomplete method would be best. `ajaxStop()` is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58011/discussion-between-kris-hollenbeck-and-tara).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward application of jQuery, but I commented it up for you anyway:

```
//select the box element using jQuery
var box = $('#colorbox');

//get the current width and height
var curWidth = box.width();
var curHeight = box.height();

//set the width and height with modified values
box.width(curWidth + 28);
box.height(curHeight + 55);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/579s2/

Comment: Mike, that script looks like it would work (and it definitely does in the fiddle), but its not working on my website. I did call the jquery correctly, right? (please see edited original post for more details)